# CoGroupByKey, emit after n records have been grouped

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to parallelize some heavier computations like so:

```py
inputs = (p | "Read" >> beam.io.ReadFromAvro('/mypath/myavrofiles*')
            | "Generate Key" >> beam.Map(lambda row: (gen_key(row), row)))

calc1_results = inputs | "perform calc1" >> beam.Pardo(Calc1())
calc2_results = inputs | "perform calc2" >> beam.Pardo(Calc2())

combined = (({"calc1": calc1_results, "calc2": calc2_results})
            | beam.CoGroupByKey()
            | beam.Values())

final = combined | "Use Grouped results" >> beam.ParDo(PerformFinalCalculation())
```

- Each heavy calc emits `(key, result)`
- Each key is unique for each input. One input, One result, one Key

Is there some way to emit from the `CoGroupByKey` after a single `result1`/`result2` has been collected for each key?

Ultimately I'd like to achieve something along the lines of:

```
               +------------+
               |            |
               |   Input    |
               |            +-----------------+
               +------------+                 |
                     |                        |
          v-------------------v               |
  +------------+       +------------+         |
  |            |       |            |         |
  |  Heavy     |       |   Heavy    |         |
  |  Calc 1    |       |   Calc 2   |         |
  |            |       |            |         |
  +------------+       +------------+         |
             |            |                   |
             |            |                   |
             |            |                   |
          +--v------------v--+                |
          |      Merged      |                |
          |  original dict,  +<---------------+
          |result 1, result2 |
          |                  |
          +------------------+
```

Comment: I can imagine that using ```tags``` will help you out. Could you please tell me what is the input and what is the expected result you are trying to achieve and I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Certainly @dbustosp. The input is a row of data - think information about a single item, some historical data and other features, normalized such that each row has all the data it needs. 

There are a few predictions / transformations we want run on each row, which can be performed concurrently. 

Then, we want to combine the results for each row. The combination can happen independently for each row. Order of the rows does not matter. Once all results for one row have been collected, it can continue through the pipeline.